# update or reset keystore not working on play store

Tags: android, apk, google-play-console

I have lost my keystore file so i made a request to google play console. as they have told me I have sent a pem file with particular fingerprint. and then I got this mail with new fingerprints.

**Info We've received a request to reset your upload key
We've received a request to reset your upload key for Brand Studio (com.xxx.xxx). The new upload key will become valid on Oct 16, 2023 at 6:38 AM UTC. Until the new upload key becomes valid, you can't upload any new app bundles or APKs.**

but now I am trying to upload a new aab file of bundle then it is showing me.

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key.
```

what do I do now ?